# About problem A4 2022 of Putnam

Tags: probability, contest-math

I'm not passing the William Lowell Putnam competition (I live in France) but I'm still fascinated by some of the problems.

This year the A4 problem challenged me and I wanna know your thoughts about it :

---

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots$ real numbers between $0$ and $1$ that are chosen independently and uniformly at random.

Let $S = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{X_i}{2^i}$ where $k$ is the least positive integer such that $X_k < X_{k+1}$ or $k=\infty$ if there is no such integer.

Find the expected value of $S$.

---

**1** - Is this a classic problem that Putnam competitors know ?

**2** - What's the idea to solve this ?

Instictively I would say that :
$$\mathbb{E}[S] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{X_i}{2^i} \right] = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_i]}{2^i} = \displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{E}[X_1]}{2} + \displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{E}[X_2]}{4} + \dots + \displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{E}[X_k]}{2^k}$$

And then calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_k]$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$ but maybe that's not the right idea and the solution is far more exotic.

Comment: My simulations (if I have understood the question) suggest something slightly less than $0.3$.

Comment: Putnam questions and solutions for all years can be found [here](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/).

Comment: It's a 2022 problem, there are no solutions for the moment !

Comment: @AxelArno Here: https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2022s.pdf. These aren't the full solutions but these are solutions nevertheless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The probability that $X_1>\cdots>X_n\ge t$ is $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(1-t)^{n-1}$

$$E(X_n)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(n-1)!}t(1-t)^{n-1}dt=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}B(2, n)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$
$$E[S]=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{i}}E(X_i)= \frac{1}{2^{i}(i+1)!}=2\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{i}i!}=2\left(e^{1/2}-1-\frac{1}{2^{1}\cdot 1!}\right)=2e^{\frac{1}{2}}-3$$

by Taylor series $$e^{\frac{x}{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!2^n}x^n$$

Comment: That (about $0.29744$) looks consistent with my simulations

Comment: $k$ is a random variable. How do pull that out of the expectation?

Comment: @Trailblazer I changed notations.

Comment: That was savage! Where did the first claim come from though?

Answer (score 10):

Note that $k = \inf\{j \ge 1 : X_j < X_{j+1} \}$ is random itself (i.e $k(\omega) = \inf\{j \ge 1 : X_j(\omega) < X_{j+1}(\omega)\}$, hence you cannot write something like $\mathbb E[\sum_{j=1}^k "something"] = \sum_{j=1}^k \mathbb E["something"]$ because then the left hand side is deterministic (as an expected value of something), whereas the right hand side remains random (due to the randomness of $k=k(\omega)$).

Note that when $k=k(\omega)$ is some fixed value, then $X_1(\omega) \ge X_2(\omega) \ge ... \ge X_k(\omega)$ and $X_k(\omega) < X_{k+1}(\omega)$. In other words, on the set $\{\omega : k(\omega) = N\}$, your random variables $X_1,...,X_N$ are in non-increasing order, whereas the last one we are focused on, that is, $X_{N+1}$, is greater than $X_N$. Similarly, on the set $\{\omega : k(\omega) \ge N\}$ you just need to have $X_1 \ge ... \ge X_N$.

Let $1_A$ be the indicator (characteristic function) of the set $A$. Note that by Fubinii's theorem, $$ \mathbb E[S] = \mathbb E[\sum_{N=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^N \frac{X_j}{2^j} 1_{\{k = N\}}] = \sum_{N=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{2^j}\mathbb E[X_j 1_{\{k = N\}}] = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j} \sum_{N=j}^\infty \mathbb E[X_j 1_{\{k=N\}}] = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j}\mathbb E[X_j 1_{\{k \ge j\}}].  $$ Hence, we're left with calculating $\mathbb E[X_j 1_{\{k \ge j\}}]$. By the conditional expectation, $$ \mathbb E[X_j 1_{\{k \ge j\}}] = \mathbb E[ \mathbb E[X_j 1_{\{ k \ge j\}} | X_j]] = \mathbb E[X_j  \mathbb E[1_{\{k \ge j\}} | X_j] ]. $$ The inner expectation $\mathbb E[1_{k \ge j} |X_j] = \mathbb P(k \ge j | X_j)$ boils down to calculating the probability that $X_1 \ge X_2 \ge ... \ge X_{j-1} \ge X_j$ (where $X_j$ is some fixed value, due to independence), hence $\mathbb P(k \ge j|X_j) = \frac{(1-X_j)^{j-1}}{(j-1)!} $. Plugging this inside, $$\mathbb E[X_j 1_{\{k \ge j\}}] = \frac{1}{(j-1)!}\mathbb E[X_j (1-X_j)^{j-1}] = \frac{1}{(j-1)!}\mathbb E[X^{j-1} - X^j] = \frac{\frac{1}{j} - \frac{1}{j+1}}{(j-1)!} = \frac{1}{(j+1)!}. $$ (We've used the fact that $X_j \sim 1-X_j$ to avoid calculating some beta integral). Hence $$ \mathbb E[S] = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j} \frac{1}{(j+1)!} = 2\left( \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^jj!} - 1 - \frac{1}{2}\right) = 2e^{\frac{1}{2}} - 3.$$

Comment: Another way to avoid a beta integral: let $Y_j = X_j 1_{k \ge j}$.  As in Hypernova's answer, $P(Y_j > t) = P((X_1 > t \cap \dots \cap X_j > t) \cap (X_1 > \dots > X_j))$ which are independent events, so $P(Y_j > t) = (1-t)^j/j!$.  Now recall the handy formula $E[X] = \int_0^\infty P(X > t)\,dt$, valid for all nonnegative random variables (the proof is one line using Fubini's theorem).  Then you only have to do an easy integral: $E[Y_j] = \frac{1}{j!} \int_0^1 (1-t)^j\,dt = \frac{1}{(j+1)!}$.

Comment: Can we compute $\mathbb{E}[X_j 1_{\{k=N\}}]$ directly? This is what I did, and I got a diverse answer, and I'm wondering why. 

Firstly, $\mathbb{P}(k=N) = \frac{N}{(N+1)!}=\frac{1}{N!}-\frac{1}{(N+1)!}$. Secondly if $X_1 > \ldots > X_N$ then $\mathbb{E}[X_i |X_1 > \ldots > X_N] = \frac{(N+1)-i}{N+1}$ because the $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ are equidistributed, the minimum being at $\frac{1}{N+1}$, the $j$'tj smallest at $\frac{j}{N+1}$ (can be shown with a beta integral). However when I plug this in I get $\sum_{k\geq 1} \sum_{1\leq i \leq k} \frac{1}{2^i} \frac{k}{(k+1)!} \frac{ (k+1)-i}{k+1}$.

Comment: Isn't it a problem that in $\{k=N\}$ you have an additional information $X_{N+1} \ge X_N$, which is missing in the part $\mathbb E[X_i | X_1 > ... > X_N]$? At least it is something that caught my eye.

Comment: Yes this is what I thought too, but I can't see why should it influence the value of 
$X_i$? I did a couple of tests, and sampling $N$ random variables distributes them expected $\frac{j}{N+1}$, while sampling $N+1$ and conditioning on first $N$ ordered and the last one unordered, again gives the same expected distribution.

Comment: I posted it as a separate question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598599/wrong-solution-to-a-putnam-problem-proof-problem