# Expected value of $i$'th smallest random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, contest-math, conditional-probability, order-statistics

Suppose we sample $k+1$ i.i.d. random variables $X_i$ uniformly at random in $[0,1]$.
What is
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_i | X_1 > X_2 > \cdots > X_k \cap X_{k+1} > X_k]?
$$

---

To start, suppose we sample $k$ i.i.d. random variables $X_i$ uniformly at random in $[0,1]$.
Let $X_i'$ be the $i$'th smallest value.  What is $\mathbb{E}[X_i']$?

I believe that it is $\frac{i}{k+1}$ and I will prove it by induction. Recall $\mathbb{E}[X_i'] = \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}(X_i' \geq t) dt$.

For the minimum, we have $\mathbb{P}(X_1' \geq t) = (1-t)^k$ since the smallest number being greater to $t$ is the same as asking all $k$ numbers to be in $[t,1]$. Therefore
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_1'] = \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}(X_1' \geq t) dt = \int_0^1 (1-t)^k dt = \frac{1}{k+1}.
$$

Now assume that this is true for $X_{i}'$ and let's prove it for $X_{i+1}'$. We will condition over $X_{i} \geq t$. In other words
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_{i+1}' \geq t) &= \mathbb{P}(X_{i+1}' \geq t \cap X_{i}' \geq t) +\mathbb{P}(X_{i+1}' \geq t \cap X_{i}' < t) \\
&=\mathbb{P}(X_{i+1}' \geq t \:|\: X_{i}' \geq t) \mathbb{P}(X_i' \geq t) + \mathbb{P}(X_{i+1}' \geq t \cap X_{i}' < t) \\
&= 1 \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_i' \geq t) + \mathbb{P}(X_{i+1}' \geq t \cap X_{i}' < t)
\end{align}

The former element of the RHS reduces by induction to $i$, while the latter probability is simply the probability of having sampled $i$ elements in $[0,t)$ and $k-i$ elements in $[t,1]$, which is
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{i+1}' \geq t \cap X_i' < t) = {k \choose i} t^i (1-t)^{k-i}dt.
$$
Therefore the expected value is
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X_{i+1}'] &= \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}(X_{i+1}' \geq t)dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}(X_{i}' \geq t)dt + \int_0^1{k \choose i} t^i (1-t)^{k-i}dt \\
&=\frac{i}{k+1} + \frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}\frac{i!(k-i)!}{(k+1)!}\\ 
&= \frac{i+1}{k+1}
\end{align}
The second integral is the beta integral $\int_0^1 t^a(1-t)^b=\frac{ a! b!}{(a+b+1)!}$, which can be easily proven by induction on $b$.

Now consider the following question:
Assume you sample $k$ values from the same distribution until $X_1 > X_2 > \ldots > X_k$. What is $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$, or in other words $\mathbb{E}[X_i | X_1 > X_2 >\ldots > X_k]$?
The only difference here is that $X_i$ are order from the largest to the smallest value, but I would say that the same arguments as above stand and $\mathbb{E}[X_i | X_1 > X_2 >\ldots > X_k] = 1-\frac{i}{k+1}$ (because $X_i' \leftrightarrow X_{k+1-i}$).
Is this correct?

My second and the main question is the following.
Assume we sample $k+1$ elements until $X_1 > X_2 > \cdots > X_k$ and $X_{k+1} > X_k$.
What is $\mathbb{E}[X_i | X_1 > X_2 > \cdots > X_k \cap X_{k+1} > X_k]$.
In other words we sample until the first $k$ elements are in decreasing order, but the $k+1$'st one is not.
Then, how do I compute $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ ?

---

EDIT: The motivation for this question comes from [About problem A4 2022 of Putnam](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592812/about-problem-a4-2022-of-putnam)

Comment: Just a suggestion: let $Y_1,\dots,Y_k,Y_{k+1}$ be iid random variables with uniform distribution on the circumference of length $1$ of a cirkel. By symmetry the arc-lengths between consecutive points have the same distribution hence have equal expectation. There are $k+1$ such lengths so this expectation must equal $\frac1{k+1}$. This can be used to get a more direct proof.

Comment: While I like the argument, I feel like it is not formal enough, and I am not 100% convinced by it. Would one of the $Y_i$'s represent the point $0$, and others the remaining $k$ points in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Indeed. At one of the $Y_i$-points (does not really matter which one) you could break the circle open and bend it to line segment of length $1$. This brings you in exactly the situation described in your question.

Comment: If you cut open at $Y_{k+1}$ then choosing the other $Y_i$ is essentially the same as what happens in your question with the $X_i$. The only difference is that the line in bended instead of straight.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Very elegant answer, beats computing those pesky beta integrals. Thank you!
Any ideas on how to proceed with the second question, $\mathbb{E}[X_i | X_1 > \ldots >X_K \cap X_{k+1} > X_k]$?

Comment: This is related to A4 Putnam 2022. There's a discussion here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592812/about-problem-a4-2022-of-putnam

Comment: Yes, linked problem is the reason that I posed this question. I wanted to compute the solution via a different method, but I believe that I made an error in the computation of the conditional expected value, so I am asking how to compute it directly.

Answer (score 2):

If $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_k, X_{k+1}$ are i.i.d. random sample, then each permutation are equally likely.

Given $X_1 > X_2 > \ldots > X_k$, for a new i.i.d. random sample $X_{k+1}$, it is equally-likely for $X_{k+1}$ to be inserted in one of the following $(k+1)$ intervals:
$$\{(-\infty, X_k), (X_k, X_{k-1}), \ldots, (X_2, X_1), (X_1, +\infty)\}$$

assuming the underlying distribution is a continuous distribution and tie can be neglected. So the new rank of the new observation $X_{k+1}$, after inserting in the original sample, will be a discrete uniform distribution on $\{1, 2, \ldots, k+1\}$ depending on which interval is chosen.

Now if we further given $X_{k+1} > X_k$, then the first interval is excluded and the remaining $k$ choices for insertion are still equally-likely. $i$ of the interval will make the new sample greater than $X_i$ and $k-i$ of them will make it less than $X_i$.

To avoid confusion, we still keep the descending ordering, but adding the total number of sample to distinguish between the original sample with the new sample after insertion. Given the original sample,

$$ X_{1:k} > X_{2:k} > \ldots > X_{k:k} $$

There is a probability $i/k$ for the new sample greater than $X_{i:k}$, and a probability of $1-i/k$ for the new sample less than $X_{i:k}$ (but still greater than $X_{k:k}$). So we have

$$ X_{i:k} = \begin{cases} 
X_{i+1:k+1} & \text{if } X_{k+1} > X_{i:k} & 
\text{with probability } \displaystyle \frac {i} {k}\\ 
X_{i:k+1} & \text{if } X_{k+1} < X_{i:k} & 
\text{with probability } \displaystyle 1 - \frac {i} {k}\end{cases}$$

Therefore by law of total probability,

$$ E[X_{i:k}|X_{1:k} > X_{2:k} > \ldots > X_{k:k} \cap X_{k+1} > X_{k:k}]
= E[X_{i+1:k+1}]\frac {i} {k} + E[X_{i:k+1}]\left(1 - \frac {i} {k}\right)$$

In particular when the sample are from $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$, the above become
$$ \left(1 - \frac {i+1} {k+1}\right)\frac {i} {k} 
+ \left(1 - \frac {i} {k+1}\right)\left(1 - \frac {i} {k}\right)
= \frac {(k-i)i + (k+1-i)(k-i)} {k(k+1)} 
= \frac {k-i} {k} = 1 - \frac {i} {k}$$

So it does not change the expectation after insertion of the new sample.