# Stopped running sum of uniform random variables $\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{X_j}{2^j}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, contest-math, expected-value, stopping-times

This is a question on one of the official solutions to problem A4 in Putnam 2022. The problem and its solutions can be found [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/doc/AMC/2022-Putnam-solutions-Session-A.pdf). My question is about Solution 1 to A4.

$X_1, X_2, \ldots$ is a sequence of iid r.v. with uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.

Define the stopping time $k$
$$k = \min\{n \geq 1: X_{n+1} > X_n\}$$
and the random variable $S$
$$S = \sum_{j=1}^k\frac{X_j}{2^j}$$

The problem is asking for the value of $E[S]$.

Assuming that I understood it correctly, Solution 1 goes as follows. It first defines
$$F(x) := E[S1_{X_1 \leq x}]$$

Then it asserts

$$E[S1_{X_1 \leq x}\mid X_1 = u] = \begin{cases}0 & u > x \\ \frac{u}{2} + \frac{1}{2}E[S1_{X_1 \leq u}] & u \leq x \end{cases}$$

I don't see how to arrive at the expression for the case $u \leq x$. The $\frac{u}{2}$ part is clear. Where does $E[S1_{X_1 \leq u}]$ come from?

Comment: The official solution 3 is neat.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592812/about-problem-a4-2022-of-putnam) is another post on the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is also "a 'first-step analysis' that expresses the expected value for the sum starting with $X_1$ in terms of the expected value for the sum starting with $X_2$".  It is basically a slightly-easier version of the official solution 1.

Let $k_X=\min\{n\ge1:X_{n+1}>X_n\}$.
Let $g(u)=E[S|X_1=u]$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
g(u)&=E\left[\left.\sum_{j=1}^{k_X}\frac{X_j}{2^j}\right|X_1=u\right]\\
&=E\left[\frac u2+\sum_{j=2}^{k_X}\frac{X_j}{2^j}\right]\\
(\text{Let } Y_i=X_{i+1})\quad&=E\left[\frac u2+\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{k_Y}\frac{Y_i}{2^i}\right]\\
&=\frac u2+\frac12E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{k_Y}\frac{Y_i}{2^i}\right]\\
&=\frac u2+\frac12\int_{y_1=0}^{1}[k_Y>0]g(y_1)\,\text dy_1\\
&=\frac u2+\frac12\int_{y_1=0}^{u}g(y_1)\,\text dy_1\\
\end{aligned}$$
where
$k_Y=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }Y_1>u,\\
\min\{n\ge1:Y_{n+1}>Y_n\}&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$ and
the Iverson bracket $[K_Y>0]=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }Y_1>u,\\
1&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}\ $

We can see that besides $u/2$, there are contributions to $S$ that come from $X_2,X_3,\cdots$ or what are the same, $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots$. **That basically also explains "where does $E[S1_{X_1 \leq u}]$ come  from?" in the question.**

The equality above implies the differential equation
$g'(u)-g(u)/2=1/2$
with initial condition $g(0)=0$.
Hence $g(u)=e^{u/2}-1$.

$E[S]=\int_{u=0}^{1}E[S|X_1=u]\,\text du=\left.(2e^{u/2}-u)\right|_{u=0}^1=2\sqrt e-3.$

Comment: Could the downvoter please tell me why? Anyway, I just rephrased my answer slightly. There is no fundamental changes, though.

Comment: I should have mentioned the most important and obvious observation: $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots,$ is also a sequence of iid r.v. with uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.